# Schedular doesn't execute when adding array values

Tags: osgi, aem

I created a very simple schedular which execute after each minute as below :

```
@Service(value = Runnable.class)
@Component(name = "Job A", label = "Job A", description = "Job will run after 1 min", metatype = true, immediate = true)
@Properties({
        @Property(label = "Quartz Cron Expression", description = "Quartz Scheduler specific cron expression.", name = "scheduler.expression", value = "0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *"),
        @Property(unbounded=PropertyUnbounded.ARRAY, value={"*"}, label = "Root Path", name = "domain.rootpath",
                description = "Root Page"),
        @Property(
                label = "Allow concurrent executions",
                description = "Allow concurrent executions of this Scheduled Service",
                name = "scheduler.concurrent",
                boolValue = true,
                propertyPrivate = true
        )
})
public class SimpleSchedular implements Runnable {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleSchedular.class);
    private String[] rootPath;
    public void run() {
        logger.info("JOB A ::: "+rootPath.length);

    }
    @Activate
    private void activate(final ComponentContext componentContext) {
        final Dictionary<?, ?> properties = componentContext.getProperties();
        this.rootPath = (String [])properties.get("domain.rootpath");
        logger.info("JOB A Length of array ::: "+this.rootPath.length); //prints correct length
    }
    @Modified
    private void modified(final ComponentContext componentContext) {
        activate(componentContext);
    }
}
```

When i build the code, this code works fine and print `JOB A ::: 1` after one min. But when i add few more values via `domain.rootpath` via OSGi console,its not call the run method. I can see the correct array length when activate calls but run menthod doesn't execute. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have call on run and activate method happens at same time after using sling documentation https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/scheduler-service-commons-scheduler.html I used the different approach to create scheduler. Below is sample code which works for me.

```
@Component(name = "Hello World Schedular", label = "Simple Schedular", metatype = true)
@Properties(
        @Property(unbounded= PropertyUnbounded.ARRAY, value={"/content/PwC/en"}, label = "Root Path", name = "domain.rootpath",
                description = "Root Page to create the sitemap")
)
public class HelloWorldScheduledService {
    protected final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    @Reference
    private Scheduler scheduler;
    protected void activate(ComponentContext componentContext) throws Exception {
        final Dictionary<?, ?> properties = componentContext.getProperties();
        final String arr[] = (String [])properties.get("domain.rootpath");
        String schedulingExpression = "0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *";
        String jobName1 = "case1";
        Map<String, Serializable> config1 = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
        boolean canRunConcurrently = true;
        final Runnable job1 = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                log.info("Executing job1"+arr.length);
            }
        };
        try {
            this.scheduler.addJob(jobName1, job1, config1, schedulingExpression, canRunConcurrently);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            job1.run();
        }
    }

    protected void deactivate(ComponentContext componentContext) {
        log.info("Deactivated, goodbye!");
    }

    protected void modified(ComponentContext componentContext){
       try{
           activate(componentContext);
       }catch (Exception e){

       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that removing the `@Modified` method would fix things. If you don't have that, your component will be deactivated and reactivated when its OSGi configuration changes, and the Sling scheduler subsystem should then pick up changes correctly.